# How to fetch specific word from long string with particular keyword

Tags: java

I have a string as below:-

this string is an output of a command which find all services entry in the config file and print out.
here A B C etc are services and respective services entry or config parameters.

```
   MAP(S):   service.cfg      OS_SERV 0 0 0 50 50 1 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\olaunch" -f "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\osserv"      GUI
SVR 0 0 1 99 99 2 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\olaunch" -f "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\omf" -a      netcap 0 1 1 1 1 60 "D:\workdir\UP
G_81\bin\netcap"      netprobe 0 0 0 99 99 1 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\netprobe"      lamserv 1 1 1 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\
bin\lamserv"      mserv 1 1 1 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\mserv"      uidserv 1 1 1 1 1 10  "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\uidser
v"      rserv 0 1 1 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\rserv"      nlsserv 1 1 1 1 1 10  "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\nlsserv"      om
fsvr 1 1 25 25 25 60 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\objserv" -C 250      searchserv 0 0 0 12 12 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\search" -
s searchserv      notifserv 0 0 0 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\notif" -C 250      notifservbroker 0 0 0 1 1 10 "D:\workdir
\UPG_81\bin\eventqb" -s notifservbroker      mloader 1 1 1 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\mloader"      postserv 0 1 1 3 3 1
0 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\post" -h       advancerserv 0 0 0 3 3 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\advancer" -C 250      advancerserv
broker 0 0 0 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\eventqb" -s advancerservbroker      scheduleserv 0 1 1 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81
\bin\schedule"      registry 0 1 1 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\rgyserv"      repserv 0 0 0 0 0 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\
replic8r"      repservbroker 0 0 0 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\eventqb" -s repservbroker      cacheserv 0 1 1 1 1 10 "D:\
workdir\UPG_81\bin\cachesche" -C 250      eventlogger 0 0 1 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\eventlogger" -s      expireserv 0
 0 1 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\expire"      partEOLserv 0 0 1 1 1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\partEOL" -R 90      msqlpdm
m81dm 0 0 25 25 25 2 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\msqlora" -sn D:\workdir\UPG_81\config\pdmm81dm.pwf -C 5000      mgrsvr 0 0 1 1
1 10 "D:\workdir\UPG_81\bin\mgrora"
```

I want to fetch `D:\workdir\UPG_81\config\pdmm81dm.pwf`  of service `msqlpdmm81dm` from this string using java and this password file cloud be with -s , -n or -sn option.
please suggest a better way.

it was working fine with this code,

cfgtest is my utility which parses the configuration file and returns specific entry from the config file.

```
  Process p  = _executeProcess("cfgtest","-m","service.cfg");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( p.getInputStream() ) );

 String s = br.readLine();
 while ( s != null )
 {
    if ( s.matches( "^\\s*msql.*$" ) ) 
    {
       StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer( s, " " );
       while ( st.hasMoreTokens() )
       {
          if ( st.nextToken().equals( "-sn" ) )
          {
             pwf = st.nextToken();
          }
       }
    }
    s = br.readLine();
 }
 br.close();
```

but now I change approach and try with some function which returns cfgtest command output as a single string.

```
 String cmd = "cfgtest -m service.cfg";
int dstat = shell._execCommand(cmd);
String s = null;  
 s = shell._getCommandOutput();
 System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Post some code that you tried

Comment: A better way than what?